# Using State/City in form dropdown in Code Igniter

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, webforms

I have a codeigniter webform, I want to input city/state details from the user, such that when user selects State; the city dropdown refreshes to contain names of cities in that State. 
I don't want to write an array of all the US states and cities for the code ignitor form, there must have been a module or any other support for that, in which I select a State and it filters the cities dropdown for it.

What's the best way to achieve it? I mean do code igniter have builtin library for it? or any support from jquery?

Comment: so what problem you are having

Comment: I assume the reason [your identical question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9094288/615754) was closed is that you don't actually ask a question, you just state a series of facts. You need to show some of your code and explain what you're having trouble with. (What you're probably going to need to do is populate the State dropdown from your DB when the page is first generated, then you could use jQuery's Ajax mthods to get a list of cities when the user selects a state.)

Comment: my bad :) yeah it did happened

Comment: the thing is that i dont want to write a whole array of us states and cities and then use in my form, i need some good written library for it, which has to be a best practice

Comment: I seriously doubt someone has a handy array of all US states and cities.  You're wanting a database (and someone else to do your homework for you, for that matter).  You should pay to subcontract this kind of stuff... :P

Comment: like i remember drupal has a module for it, thats the beauty of opensource :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to populate the database or write the array for the US States and cities, why don't you search for the sql dump for it. Here is a link from where you can download the sql dump.

http://www.farinspace.com/us-cities-and-state-sql-dump/

Then you can use ajax to load cities when the selection in the dropdown menu is changed.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to collect all geographical data yourselft -  you could use one from here - http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/national/html/cities.htm for free, or from here - http://citydatabase.us/ for money